# What's the difference between window.open(url) and window.location.href = url on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to build a bookmarklet, feeding the current url as a parameter to another url.

However I am finding out that this

```
javascript:(function(){window.open("http://www.somesi.te/some/thing?url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href))})()
```

does not work, while this

```
javascript:(function(){window.location.href = "http://www.somesi.te/some/thing?url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)})()
```

does. Apart from the obvious difference that `window.open` opens another window, and `window.location.href` changes location, why does the latter work, while the former just opens another window to the original location?

This is on Firefox. Funnily enough, on Chrome things work fine.

Is this a security thing?

Comment: *this does not work* - how exactly, the new window in not being opened? If so, check Firefox is not blocking the popup.

Comment: `javascript:` links are pretty much always evil. Please, on behalf of your users, don't use them!

Comment: @lonesomeday Though I share the sentiment, when it comes to bookmarklets there's no other option.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed. Quite right.

Comment: So, it looks like this `javascript:(function(){var w = window.open(""); w.location.href = "http://www.somesi.te/some/thing?url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)})()`  works. Not a popup blocking thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between `window.open()` and `window.location.href` is that `open()` is a **method** of the window class, and `window.location` is a **property** of the window class.

**1.`window.open()` is a *method* on the window class**

Calling the `window.open()` method actually creates a window object, which can be held in a variable and manipulated according to your program's requirements.

To demonstrate that window.open() actually returns a window object, consider the following code:

```
var mywindow = window.open("http://google.com");
mywindow.name = "Awesome Window";
console.log(typeof(mywindow)); // --> "object"
console.log(mywindow.name); // --> "Awesome Window"
```

The reason your code was opening an unwanted window, is because you were calling `window.open()`, whose sole purpose in life is to open a new window.

**2. `window.location` is a *read-only property* on the window class.**

Although `window.location` is a read-only property, the `window.location` has a built-in shortcut feature that allows `window.location` to be assignable, which has the same effect as calling `window.location.assign()`, which does not return a window object, but uses the root window object to assign a new url to, causing the newly-assigned url to be loaded in the browser window where the javascript assigning the location was called.

If you are creating a bookmarket script, then using `window.location` is the better way of grabbing the current window's url and assigning it to your program's url string.

The reason why you might find that you are getting unexpected behavior in different browsers, is that there is no official public standard set for the window object, so how each browser chooses to implement it behind the scenes may vary.