# Difference between window.location.assign(url) and window.open(url, '_self')

Tags: javascript, dom

What's the difference between `window.location.assign(url)` and `window.open(url, '_self')`?

---

Related questions:

- [Difference between window.location.assign() and window.location.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505798/difference-between-window-location-assign-and-window-location-replace)
- [What's the difference between window.open(url) and window.location.href = url on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605170/whats-the-difference-between-window-openurl-and-window-location-href-url-on)

Comment: What did the related answers not answer for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign vs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 5):

Functionally? Not much. They do similar things in different ways.

Personally, I'd probably choose window.location over window.open. Even though they do the same things, using window.location for changing the current window is more common, and doesn't require knowing about '_self', which isn't used that often. My experience is my coworkers expect window.open to involve opening a window versus reusing the same one.

Answer (score -4):

`window.location.assign` will assign the current window a new URL value. `window.open` will open a new window (which may be in a new tab, or not, depending) with the value of the url passed.

It's the difference between creating a new window and editing an existing window.

Comment: "window.open will open a new window" — Not with the arguments that the question has specified.